# Hover underline styles behave oddly with multi-line mathematical expressions in title, such as $\dfrac{72_8!}{18_2!}=4^x$

Tags: bug, mathjax, css

[image]

I took this screenshot while hovering my cursor over the first question. As you can see, the dotted underline cuts through the denominator of the fraction. Looks like a CSS bug.

Comment: Display-style math, such as `dfrac`, [should not be used in titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9687/). I edited the title to remove it, but included the same example here, so that the developers have a live demonstration of it. I don't really think this is a bug: the underline is correctly placed under the text, but MathJax-rendered formula protrudes beyond the space of one line.

Comment: I have this problem even for normal frac or anything that is longer than normal text (sigma etc). Does anybody else share my problem?

Comment: Is it really that bad...?